# Currency exchange calculation in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, currency-exchange-rates

I have two tables first one Account consist of following data:

```
Code | Exposure | Expo_Curr | Limit | Limit_curr | Date_extr  

2105 | 2.354586 | EUR | 288.6 | HUF | 1405  
2105 | 25.46658 | USD | 12.32 | CAD | 1203  
2105 | 5.987456 | CAD | 321.2 | CZK | 1107  
2105 | 9.658785 | HRK | 5.365 | EUR | 1103
```

Second table consist of exchange rate

```
Code | date_extr | currency_from | currency_to | fx_rate  

2105 | 1405 | HUF | EUR | 4.36  
2105 | 1203 | USD | EUR | 3.62  
2105 | 1203 | CAD | EUR | 1.23  
2105 | 1107 | CAD | EUR | 1.17  
2105 | 1107 | CZK | EUR | 24.6  
2105 | 1103 | HRK | EUR | 35.6
```

I need to create table where **Exposure** and **Limit** will be transferred to EUR currency according to exchange rate in the second table. If the data is already in EUR it should be just multiplied to 1 the rest should be calculated according to rate in second table. The rate should match also the date_extr (YYMM when rate was valid).

Should look like this:

```
Code | Exposure | Expo_Curr | Limit | Limit_curr | Date_extr  

2105 | 2.354586*1.00 | EUR | 288.6*4.36 | HUF | 1405  
2105 | 25.46658*3.62 | USD | 12.32*1.23 | CAD | 1203  
2105 | 5.987456*1.17 | CAD | 321.2*24.6 | CZK | 1107  
2105 | 9.658785*35.6 | HRK | 5.365*1.00 | EUR | 1103
```

I'm working on SAS, so I tried to do it with SQL join, but I couldn't make it work. If anyone can help to figure out how could I do it? I have more columns to calculate like this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adopt a hash-table approach, and extend the hash keys and corresponding lookups to as many match-variables as you require :

```
data want ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    /* Define & load hash table of conversions */
    length currency_from $3. date_extr fx_rate 8. ;
    declare hash exc (dataset:"exchange") ;
    exc.defineKey('currency_from','date_extr') ; /* extend this to more variables */
    exc.defineData('fx_rate') ;
    exc.defineDone() ;
    call missing(of currency_from--fx_rate) ;
  end ;

  set accounts ;

  /* Lookup Expo_Curr + date_extr in hash table */
  rc = exc.find(key:expo_curr,key:date_extr) ; /* extend this to match */
  if rc = 0 then do ;
    expo_rate = fx_rate ;
    exposure2 = exposure * expo_rate ;
  end ;

  /* Lookup Limit_Curr + date_extr in hash table */
  rc = exc.find(key:limit_curr,key:date_extr) ; /* extend this to match */
  if rc = 0 then do ;
    limit_rate = fx_rate ;
    limit2 = limit * limit_rate ;
  end ;

  drop rc ;
run ;
```

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003143739.htm

Comment: thank you very much! It works :) I will try to learn more about hashing now.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to left join on the FX table twice.  One for limit, one for exposure.

E.g.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN acc.expo_curr = 'EUR'
    THEN acc.exposure
    ELSE acc.exposure * expo.fx_rate
  END AS exposure,
  acc.expo_curr,
  CASE
    WHEN acc.limit_curr = 'EUR'
    THEN acc.limit
    ELSE acc.limit * lim.fx_rate
  END AS limit,
  acc.limit_curr
FROM account acc
LEFT JOIN exchange expo
  ON  expo.date_extr = acc.date_extr
  AND expo.currency_from = acc.expo_curr
  AND expo.currency_to = 'EUR'
LEFT JOIN exchange lim
  ON  lim.date_extr = acc.date_extr
  AND lim.currency_from = acc.limit_curr
  AND lim.currency_to = 'EUR'
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, is there any other option, because in fact I need to calculate 5 columns like this from 1 table and having 5 joins will take long time, because Account table is quite big. Thanx in advance!

Comment: Look into Hash Tables, seems like an ideal candidate for this type of problem.

Comment: @Noza don't worry about the Account table's size.  Using this query you'll only conduct a single table-scan on it.  The issue (in this case) would come if your FX tables were very large.

Comment: ..if the 5 amounts in the Account table were stored in 5 rows rather than 5 columns, the solution might be neater.

Comment: @AndyN thank you, I can't change the table Account structure, but I will try to run it with the sample you gave me. thank you very much.

Comment: @ChrisJ can you show me some small sample? I have never used hashes. may be it could be another solution?